# Can Hibernate see changes from outside the JVM?

Tags: hibernate, caching

Pardon my ignorance.

So if I load an entire table and cache it and then someone deletes one record, changes a record and inserts yet another record... if these events take place in the database via SQL, does Hibernate's loaded and cached version of the table know about the changes?

Answer (score 0):

No, the cache isn't going to scan the database to update itself when the underlying data changes. Changes that do not come through the hibernate cache will not appear in it.